# Add bars / dowels to cabinet

Tags: doors, cabinets, remodeling, pet-door

I've recently purchased an entertainment center which I want to make into a dog kennel.

The dog is small (16lbs) and will fit comfortably behind the doors in the unit attached.

I've search endlessly online and am looking for the easiest solution to disassemble the doors it comes with or purchase a new door to add bar so that the kennel area has more lighting dog can see etc. Any suggestions are appriciated. Not sure how large the doors are as the unit has not arrived yet.

Entertainment Unit: https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/birch-lane-heritage-heywood-tv-stand-for-tvs-up-to-60-w000247624.html?refid=TEM_WF178294&mmid=2079860922&csnid=9AB20F9A-9F38-4D1A-8A39-67AA5C305974&libra_c=&libra_d=&libra_g=&cltr=

Comment: Dissassembling the doors and reconstructing them is a job for a carpenter. Nobody will be able to tell you how to accomplish this by looking at the picture in your link. If you have the special tools that are likely required (drill press, doweling jig, carpenter's clamps, power saw/s, pin nailer, etc.) then you would not need to ask the question. I think what you need is beyond a novice DIY job.

Comment: Expensive dog crate/kennel... Do you want this to open like a door or replace 1 door with slats? As a new door you will have to buy the material of choice...dogs chew wood easily btw...and construct your door and create hinges. Depends on your level of DIY expertise and requirements.

Comment: Most likely those are press board doors and can't be used effectively in the change also.